# Is it possible to open Word internal link to paragraph from shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, file-shortcut

Is it possible to open Word internal link to paragraph from shortcut? It was definitely  possible before and you can still do it in OneNote, but i can't find a way to do it in Word now.

Comment: As far as i know, this is impossible

Comment: In old Word (2010), I can get it to work if I have a bookmark named in my destination document.  Then in the source document hyperlink, add #bookmarkname at end of hyperlink address (eg after .docx)

Answer (score 1):

**If you are talking about a Windows shortcut, an icon on your desktop that is a shortcut to a document, the answer is "No." As far as I know this is not possible.**

If you are talking about linking from within a Word document (or Excel), then the answer is "Yes, you can." It is as Tanya said in her comment, you can add the bookmark name to your hyperlink. See the screenshot below.

[image: Dialog box to insert a hyperlink to existing document with bookmark]

**You can also add a cross-reference to a bookmark *within the same document* that will act as a hyperlink.**

Comment: Yes, i was asking about opening links to bookmarks and paragraphs in a Word document from shortcut files (.lnk extension). Well, thanks for your answer anyway.